# php - Laravel Auth and Session not working

Tags: php, session, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

The following code prints "test: bar" but not "home: bar". This code works fine locally on my XAMPP server but doesn't work on my webhost server. At first I thought it was an issue with the PHP version, but I don't think it's that anymore. I'm thinking it has to be some setting I have to enable on the webhost? Does anyone know what may be causing this?

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function home()
    {
        echo "home: " . Session::get('foo');
    }

    public function test()
    {
        Session::put('foo','bar');
        echo "test: " . Session::get('foo');
        return Redirect::route('home');
    }

}

Actual Output:
test: bar
home:

Expected Output:
test: bar
home: bar
```

Comment: can you write the routes.php?

Comment: what settings do you have listed in your config for sessions? You are probably trying to use a session that does not exist on your webserver (i.e. memcache or something)

Comment: @angoru: what do you mean by that?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange: i left everything in config/sessions.php unchanged with the default settings.

Comment: The default session is 'file' - does your server have write access to the storage folder?

Comment: @carr0lls i don't know how are you calling this two methods, you need a route to call them, write it so we can help you.

Comment: You should be using `return` instead of `echo`, not sure if that'll solve the problem though.

Comment: @JasonLewis: echo prints fine for this testing purpose, return didn't change anything. thanks though.

Comment: Regardless, we're going to need more information. Do you hit the `test` route first? Have you tried other session drivers? Have you tried declaring the session in `app/start/global.php` and then returning it in both routes?

Comment: @JasonLewis: Oh sorry! I realized I chopped off the Redirect line in the test() function (I updated the code above now). But yes, I hit the test route first and the Session is put() and prints successfully with the get(). Then it redirects to home but Session::get() then fails to get any value (should be bar). Hence, the same problem happens with Auth::login() and Auth::check, they work when they're both in the same function but once Redirected to another route, Auth::login() becomes false again which I think is due to the same reason as Sessions not being set. Thanks for the support everyone.

Comment: You *must* `return Redirect::route('home');`

Comment: @JasonLewis: again, apologies that's just a typo when typing it in here, i do have return in my code. it's functional.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel expects a response to be **returned** from a route (and controllers). Because you're not **returning** the redirect the session is not persisted and the redirect probably isn't occurring. Simply update your methods to return the correct responses:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function home()
    {
        return "home: " . Session::get('foo');
    }

    public function test()
    {
        Session::put('foo','bar');

        return Redirect::route('home');
    }

}
```

When you're returning a redirect there's no point in echoing as the response will not be seen anyway.

Comment: again, apologies that's just a typo when typing it in here, i do have return in my code. it's functional. i've updated the code block above to show it now.